# How do I convert single quote to dash and remove double quotes?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to convert single quote to dash and remove double quotes embedded in the string.

For example,
if i have a string 8'5"
it should be "8-5"

Comment: Have you looked into `String.Replace()`?

Comment: We will not write this for you without you telling us what you tried and where you are stuck. We help those that help themselves.

Answer (score 5):

Please use:

```
str = str.Replace('\'', '-').Replace("\"", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `\` to escape the `'`, then you can use [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx):

```
string original = "8'5";
string newString = original.Replace('\'', '-');
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/XOEVZT)

Comment: @Oded: i assume that that's just a typo since the desired result contains both quotes in `"8-5"`.

Comment: I think this is a string representing 8 feet and 5 inches, commonly written as `8'5"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at any C# language reference?  What you are asking is very basic.  The following code is a quick and dirty way of doing what you are asking:

```
string measurement = "8'5\"";
measurement = measurement.Replace("'", "-").Replace("\"", "");
```

The back slash is used to escape the double quote.

Comment: Except that's a backward slash!  :P

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yeah, my fingers didn't type what my brain told them, too.  Darn fingers.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding:

```
        string str = "8\'5\"";

        //one row version
        str = str.Replace('\'', '-').Insert(0, "\"");
        Console.WriteLine(str);            

        //multi row version, just for understanding
        str = "8\'5\"";            
        str = str.Replace('\'', '-');            
        str = str.Insert(0, "\"");
```